# Notifying about a new email using DNS

Tags: email, dns, gmail

I have a domain registered and connected to an email (gmail specifically).
I now want to cancel paying the email provided and will be keeping the domain for another year.

Is it possible to leave a notification on the DNS side to use a different email?

Example:

> Someone sends an email to name@mydomain.com, that can't be delivered any more because there isn't an end point. Instead there is an email response saying "That email is no longer available, please sent to othermail@gmail.com

I'm open to alternative suggestions just want to avoid having to pay for an email service to achieve this.

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: Certainly **No** for somehow responding to an email using DNS. An alternative is finding some free email service (or at least email forwarding service) for your domain. Who is your domain registered with (Google Domains has free Email forwarding)?

Comment: Thanks, seems like the answer is something like: "No this isn't provided on the DNS level, however DNS registers are known to provide such a feature under different names"?

Whoever answers it in an answer I will accept it.